# Filters in rails for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, filtering

How can I make a dynamic query in Rails (I'm pretty new to this framework and also to ruby).

In my controller I have:

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.where(active:1).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @categories= Category.all
  end
end
```

And part of my view is like:

```
   .filter-product
      =form_tag do
        %table#id-form 
          %tr
            %th{valign: "top"} Product name:
            %td
              %input.inp-form{type: "text"}/
            %td
          %tr
            %th{valign: "top"} Category:
            %td
              %select
                %option{value: ""} All
                - @categories.each do  |cat|
                  %option{value: cat.id}= cat.label
            %td
          %tr
            %th{valign: "top"} Stock:
            %td
              %input.inp-form{type: "checkbox"}/
            %td
          %tr
            %th  
            %td{valign: "top"}
              %input.form-submit{type: "button", value: ""}/
              %input.form-reset{type: "reset", value: ""}/
            %td
```

I want to filter my products by title, availability(stock) and also categories. The query should also work when these are not set.

I have tried  at least 3-4 ways and none of them worked.

Edit :
Here are my models:

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :category
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :products
    end
```

Comment: I've cleaned your question. Please pay a little more attention to your layout and spelling. FYI, Rails is a framework, Ruby is a language. When you say filter, do you mean you want to search for the items - can you share some of the attempts you have already made.

Comment: Also, please share how is category associated with product. I mean the association

Comment: Sorry,next time i will try to be clearer.
I have tryed somethig like this 

@products = Product.where(active:1,"title like ?",params[:title]).paginate(:page => params[:page]

Comment: I have added my models to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following way:

```
Product.where(active:1,"title like ?", "category_id = ?", params[:title].presence || '%%', params[:category_id].presence || Category.all.collect(&:id) ).paginate(:page => params[:page]...
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try to "standardize" your filters using a gem like Ransack. This way you don't have to write all code yourself, and Ransack perfectly integrates with your existing pagination. DRY also means "don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to"...